# extract maximal set of independent columns from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0  0  0  0
 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1  1  0  0
 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0  0  0  0
 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0
 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0
```

You can see every two columns are identical, indicating the "group membership" of the design matrix. Now my question is, how can I convert this rank-deficient matrix (rank = 6) into a full-rank matrix **automatically** in R? This case may be a little bit special, i.e. I can delete duplicate columns manually. I am just curious if there is an approach that solve the problem "more generally". Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? Convert by subsetting rows, by subsetting columns, by going through some other transformation?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I mean making this matrix full rank...

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear: I'm asking what transformations can be done to turn the matrix into a full-rank matrix. After all, any matrix can be "turned into a full rank matrix" just by *replacing* it with a completely different matrix that happens to be full rank. Presumably you're looking for a way to convert the matrix that involves as few steps as possible, or gets to a matrix that is as similar as possible with the original.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I think what I need is to remove the linearly dependent columns of the matrix in R, automatically. Sorry about the confusion, and thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the way R does QR decomposition this works (and by works I mean leaves a set of independent columns):

```
m[, qr(m)$pivot[seq_len(qr(m)$rank)]]
```

On the example from OP:

```
m = structure(c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(6L, 12L
))

m[, qr(m)$pivot[seq_len(qr(m)$rank)]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    0    0    1    0
#[4,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
#[5,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
#[6,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: thanks a lot! BTW, what is "OP" you are referring to? :)

Comment: OP = original post(er)

Comment: @eddi, would you be willing to share a reference showing why this works? I.e. why the pivots from the Householder algorithm put all the linearly independent columns first?

Comment: @landau that's basically the definition of the QR transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Rectangular_matrix

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
X[,duplicated(cor(X))]
```

cor(x) computes the correlation matrix of x.  If two columns are linearly dependent to each other they'll have the same column in the correlation matrix

This will get rid of the columns that are a linear transformations of a single other column.

If you're looking for row reduced echelon form instead, which will show you if a column is a linear combination of multiple other columns, check out this answer:

[Reduced row echelon form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126759/reduced-row-echelon-form)

Comment: doesn't work for e.g. `matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,2), nrow = 3)`

Comment: still doesn't work - am I missing smth?

Comment: What about numerical accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove identical columns you can do this for example:

```
 t(unique(t(dat)))
     V1 V3 V5 V7 V9 V11
[1,]  1  1  1  1  1   1
[2,]  1  1  1  0  0   0
[3,]  0  1  0  0  1   0
[4,]  1  0  0  1  0   0
[5,]  0  1  0  0  0   0
[6,]  1  0  0  0  0   0
```